# Can anyone identify this 12V DC power connector found on a radio transmitter?

Tags: dc, connector, identification, cables

This connector is used on the back of a [QYT KT-8900D radio](http://qrznow.com/qyt-kt-8900d-dual-band-quad-standby-colorful-screen-mini-mobile-vehicle-mounted/), in between the radio unit and a cigarette lighter-type plug. The unit itself takes between 12V and 15V, and I think less than 2A of current.

I'm looking for some sort of standard name.

[image: overview photo of connector]
[image: straight-on view of connector]

Comment: [6.3mm+blade+multiple+connectors](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1050&bih=1590&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=6.3MM+BLADE+MULTIPLE+CONNECTORS)

Comment: Thanks @Transistor - that helps a little - ideally I'm looking for some sort of part number that I can order off of Amazon or Digi-Key, and this helps a bit.

Comment: Be aware that shopping questions are not allowed and quickly closed down. I gave you the terminology so you could do the shopping yourself.

Comment: This is known as an OEM-T connector. Rated to 20 amps. It contains a pair of spade crimp on connectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the Kenwood part number is PG-2N, the connector is actually made by 3M.  You didn't say which gender you needed, but you can start here:

[https://www.amazon.com/Agile-Shop-T-Shape-Kenwood-TM-G707-TM-D700/dp/B01N0E7S8I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N0E7S8I)

Bare connector:

https://powerwerx.com/oemt-power-connector-source-side

BTW, consider just cutting this connector off and putting [Anderson Powerpoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_Powerpole) on instead.

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for the tip - I didn't want to alter the cable in its current form, but I will consider putting alternate connectors on.

Comment: This is known as an OEM-T connector.  Rated to 20 amps.  It contains a pair of spade crimp on connectors.